# Drag and Drop reordering

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I want to have drag and drop reordering in a list box. Just like the home screen of the phone does. I.e long press will select the item, then we should be able to drag and drop it to another location. How can this be done? Are there already any controls available?

Environment is Windows Phone 7.1

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SL4DragDropListBox.aspx?pageflow=Fluid&fid=1572066&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick) is a WPF solution for two listboxes, bot from this you should be able to make minor modifications and apply it on your solution.